# relative position and left and right property together not working, only left is working

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using this tree grid directive [github.com](https://github.com/khan4019/tree-grid-directive/), and below css is taken directly from this library.

```
.tree-grid .level-2 .indented {
    position : relative;
    left     : 20px;
}

<td><a ng-click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)"><i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon"></i></a><span class="indented tree-label tree-grid-row level-2>
             Citi Corporate and Investment Banking</span>
            </td>
```

The problem i am having is that span inside td is overflow and showing in the next column, for that purpose i need to add right:20px, but it is not working.

Is there any solution to this problem
[plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/XHzJgtJvuVAmkKn5vgPd?p=preview)

Comment: provide a simple html demo that represents problem. *"not working"* is not a proper problem description that tells us much...especially when not much code is given and we don't know how you are modifying anything. See [mcve]

Comment: padding-right: 20px. You're misunderstanding what right and left do.

Comment: have a look at the plunkr above, you can notice the styling that is there for level 3 or 4 node, and how can i make it so that it doesn't content doesn't overlap next column

Answer (score 0):

when changing existing *left* CSS rule to *right*, you should pass `left: auto;` along with your *left* value:

```
SOME_OVERRIDE {
  left: auto;
  right: NEW_VALUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to add margins to your span element. For this, use the *margin-right* and *margin-left* properties.

It does not make sense to use *left* and *right* at the same time. You can only position relative to one vertical and one horizontal side of the parent box element.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/XHzJgtJvuVAmkKn5vgPd?p=preview

 can you try to fix

Answer (score 0):

Just adding `padding-right: 20px;` gives what you are asking.

I selected the targeted span from CSS like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="abas-web">
  ...
  <body>
  ...
  <style>
    span.indented.tree-label {
      left: auto !important;
      padding-left: 60px;
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
  </style>
  </body>

</html>
```

Note: I am using `!important` to override the style settings you have placed previously. That is for demo purposes only. You should remove the `left` style rather than overriding it like that.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fGmIpG6rDlSLkhyC3kpp?p=preview)

Comment: your demo also has issues, some content in the Name column is crossed over into next column

Comment: @ua_boaz, Can you show me a screenshot? May be you just need a word-wrap.

Comment: You need to change your styling approach. Instead of `left` use `padding-left`. See the update